# couldn`t add my mongoose model to Database

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose model and I want to pass my request body data to it and then with create function add it to my database, but it doesn't work and it doesn't give me any errors and it just stock in request
there is my model

```
const usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "first name is required"],
    trim: true,
    minlength: {
      value: 2,
      message: "your first name could not be less than 2 characters!",
    },
    maxlength: {
      values: 25,
      message: "your first name could not be more than 25 characters!",
    },
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "last name is required"],
    trim: true,
    minlength: {
      values: 2,
      message: "your last name could not be less than 2 characters!",
    },
    maxlength: {
      values: 35,
      message: "your last name could not be more than 35 characters!",
    },
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: [true, "username has already been used!"],
    required: [true, "username is required!"],
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: {
      values: 6,
      message: "your username must be at least 6 characters",
    },
    maxlength: {
      values: 35,
      message: "your user name could not be bigger than 35 characters",
    },
  },
  userType: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "usertype is required"],
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    enum: {
      values: ["user", "admin"],
      message: "each user can only be admin or user",
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "please enter a password for your account"],
    select: false,
    minlength: [8, "your password could not be less than 8 characters"],
    maxlength: [64, "your password could not be more than 64 characters"],
  },
  confirmPassword: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "please confirm your password"],
    validate: {
      validator: function (val) {
        return this.password === val;
      },
      message: "your passwords are not same",
    },
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    unique: [true, "this email has already been used!"],
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: String,
    unique: [true, "this phone number has already been used!"],
    minlength: [11, "phone numbers has the length of 11 characters!"],
    maxlength: [11, "phone numbers has the length of 11 characters!"],
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "gender field could not be empty!"],
    enum: {
      values: ["male,female"],
      message: "you must be either male or female!",
    },
  },
  birthDate: {
    type: Date,
  },
  confirmedEmail: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: [true, "email confirmation must be specified as true or false"],
  },
  confirmedPhone: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: [
      true,
      "phone number confirmation must be specified as true or false",
    ],
  },
  userTickets: [
    {
      matchId: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "matchId could not be empty!"],
      },
      ticketId: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "matchId could not be empty!"],
      },
    },
  ],
});
const userModel = mongoose.model("users", usersSchema);

module.exports = userModel;
```

and this is my controller

```
exports.insertUser = async (req, res) => {
  await userModel.create(req.body);
  res.status(201).json({
    status: "success",
    message: "documents added to DB successfully",
  });
};
```

I changed my model and it works but it doesn't work with this model

Comment: Put the create function into the try catch after that console.log(error), and show the error

Comment: it doesn't throw any errors, thats my problem

Comment: At the first of inserUser function console.log(req.body), show me the result, instead of create, use save()

Comment: i try that before and nothing is wrong with that as well :(, its gonna blow my mind  {
  firstName: 'asfe3w',
  lastName: 'afsfe',
  username: 'asf3',
  userType: 'admin',
  password: 'sffasfas',
  confirmPassword: 'asdasdas',
  email: 'ssssss@ghaderi.com',
  phoneNumber: '412421241',
  gender: 'female',
  birthDate: '2002-06-05',
  confirmedEmail: true,
  confirmedPhone: true,
  userTickets: []
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the schema like this:

```
{
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "first name is required"],
    trim: true,
    minlength: [
       2,
      "your first name could not be less than 2 characters!",
    ],
    maxlength: [
      25,
      "your first name could not be more than 25 characters!"
    ]
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "last name is required"],
    trim: true,
    minlength: [
      2,
     "your last name could not be less than 2 characters!",
   ],
   maxlength: [
     25,
     "your last name could not be more than 25 characters!"
   ]
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: [true, "username has already been used!"],
    required: [true, "username is required!"],
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: [
      2,
     "your user name could not be less than 2 characters!",
   ],
   maxlength: [
     35,
     "your user name could not be more than 25 characters!"
   ]
  },
  userType: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "usertype is required"],
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    enum: {
      values: ["user", "admin"],
      message: "each user can only be admin or user",
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "please enter a password for your account"],
    select: false,
    minlength: [8, "your password could not be less than 8 characters"],
    maxlength: [64, "your password could not be more than 64 characters"],
  },
  confirmPassword: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "please confirm your password"],
    validate: {
      validator: function (val) {
        return this.password === val;
      },
      message: "your passwords are not same",
    },
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    unique: [true, "this email has already been used!"],
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: String,
    unique: [true, "this phone number has already been used!"],
    minlength: [11, "phone numbers has the length of 11 characters!"],
    maxlength: [11, "phone numbers has the length of 11 characters!"],
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "gender field could not be empty!"],
    enum: {
      values: ["male", "female"],
      message: "you must be either male or female!",
    },
  },
  birthDate: {
    type: Date,
  },
  confirmedEmail: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: [true, "email confirmation must be specified as true or false"],
  },
  confirmedPhone: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: [
      true,
      "phone number confirmation must be specified as true or false",
    ],
  },
  userTickets: [
    {
      matchId: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "matchId could not be empty!"],
      },
      ticketId: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "matchId could not be empty!"],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

because for using of `minlength` and `maxlength` is used this format :

```
    minlength: [
       2,
      "your first name could not be less than 2 characters!",
    ]
```

use `values: ["male","female"]` for gender instead of `values: ["male,female"]` because you are missing `"`

in the sample of body request

```
 {
    "lastname": "name",
    "firstname": "family",
    "username": "asf3",
    "userType": "admin",
    "password": "123456789",
    "confirmPassword": "123456789",
    "email": "ssssss@ghaderi.com",
    "phoneNumber": "12123456789",
    "gender": "female",
    "birthDate": "2002-06-05",
    "confirmedEmail": true,
    "confirmedPhone": true,
    "userTickets": []
  }
```

in the sample of req.body you use `firstName` and `lastName` with uppercase `N` but in the schema are `firstname` and `lastname`

use try/catch like this:

```
exports.insertUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let newUser = new userModel(req.body)
    await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      message: "documents added to DB successfully",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      status: "faild",
      message: "something went wrong",
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I copy your model it didn't work again. my code reaches the line before model.create and it stock on model.create

Comment: Copy the req.body also, I tested it works for me, check anothert things, because I solved the problems about schema and req.body

Comment: I copied ur controller and now it's working, I change ur controller code to model.create and it was working again, but when I comment your controller out and use my own controller it stocks again :D, its so strange, but thanks for your help, it's working well with your code